# Running two different PHP fast-cgi instances on windows with OPCache enabled

Tags: windows, php, php5, fastcgi, php.ini

I'm trying to run two different `php 5.5` instances on Windows (one with XDebug, one without, same php executable, different `php.ini` files) over `fast-cgi` in Apache 2.4, ideally both with opcache enabled.

However when I enable opcache for both one of the versions shows `500 Internal Server Error` when accessing the page and the error log for the php versions then includes the entry

```
Die Pipe wurde beendet.  [[Translation: The Pipe has been terminated]] : [client 192.168.10.232:60702] mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
```

It seems that both php instances are accessing the same shared memory segment for caching data and xdebug is messing things up. 
How can I configure php so this works?

Comment: Error i being reported by mod_fcgid suggesting that its a problem comiunicating te FPM rather than in the PHP backend. I assume that FPM is not reporting anything amiss?

Comment: I'm not using FPM, I'm running php-cgi directly. And aside from the mentioned log entry nothing is reported.